# Jquery: Input type="button"with .click() function dont work in Internet Explorer and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, explorer

How to make input `type="button"` with `jquery` function `.click()` work in
Internet Explorer and Safari? It works fine in Mozilla, Chrome, and Opera. 
Example, wenn button is clicked hidden div is showed:

```
<input type="button" value="Comments(<?php echo $commentCounter?>)" data-id="<?php echo $productArray[$key]["ID"].$_SESSION["userSession"];?>" class="CommentsSection"/>
<div id="<?php echo $productArray[$key]["ID"].$_SESSION["userSession"];?>" style="display:none">
<?php
echo"This is hidden div";
?>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".CommentsSection").click(function(){
    var sectionID=$(this).attr('data-id');
$("#"+sectionID).show();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you paste the generated HTML instead of php code ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your JS is loaded and executed before your HTML is rendered.
You could enclose your JS in a documentReady event (and close your onclick parenthesis) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".CommentsSection").click(function(){
      var sectionID=$(this).attr('data-id');
      $("#"+sectionID).show();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should suit your purposes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".CommentsSection").click(function(ev){
      ev.preventDefault();

      var sectionID=$(this).data('id');
      $("#"+sectionID).show();
   });
});
```

My additions are:

Use the `data()` JQuery function instead

Wait for document ready

Prevent the default behaviour

Comment: If I use `data()` instead of `attr()`,then it doesnt work in all browsers.

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".CommentsSection").click(function(ev){

ev.preventDefault();

var sectionID=$(this).data('data-id');
$("#"+sectionID).show();
   });
});
</script>`